# Wrapper for pointer to either constant or dynamic data (in C++11)

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

```
struct Item
{
    Item() = default;
    Item(int x, const char* s) : n{x}, text{s} {}

    int n{};
    const char* text;
};

static const size_t someSize = 2;
static const Item someItems[someSize] = {
    {0, "Some constant item"},
    {1, "Another constant item"}
};

class Foo
{
    void addArray(Item* a, size_t s) { itemArrays.emplace_back(a, s); }
    std::vector<std::pair<Item*, size_t>> itemArraysWithTheirSize{};
}

int main()
{
   size_t someCalculatedSize = 10; /* Not known compile-time */
   Item* someOtherItems = new Item[someCalculatedSize]{
      {0, "I'm only initializing"},
      {1, "The first two items"},
   }
   for (int i = 2; i < someCalculatedSize; i++)
   {
      someOtherItems[i] = {i, "Initialized later on"};
   }

   Foo foo;
   foo.addArray(someItems, someSize);
   foo.addArray(someOtherItems, someCalculatedSize);

   for (std::pair<const Item*, size_t>& a : foo.itemArraysWithTheirSize)
   {
      for (size_t i = 0; i < a.second; i++)
      {
         printf("%i %s\n", a.first[i].n, a.first[i].text);
      }
      printf("\n");
   }
}
```

Link to code: https://godbolt.org/z/b4M5Kjhh9

I want to be able to rewrite `Foo` so that I don't need to explicitly know the size everywhere.

My guess is I'd need a wrapper for `Item*` that I can initialize in the two ways shown in the code: with constant data (on the stack) and with dynamic data (on the heap). The first being much more common. Therefore, simply using `std::vector` for everything doesn't seem like a good solution to me.

A few requirements for this wrapper:

1. It can contain either type of data
2. The pointer to the data doesn't change
3. It contains both the capacity and the current filling of the array
4. In the case of static data, it infers its size from the constructor argument (an initializer list if possible)

So basically, how do I get this code to work (https://godbolt.org/z/fqEhYxTGz)

```
struct Item
{
    Item() = default;
    Item(int x, const char* s) : n{x}, text{s} {}

    int n{};
    const char* text;
};

struct ItemWrapper
{
    /* What do these constructors look like? */

    Item* array;
    size_t current_length;
    const size_t max_length;
};

static const ItemWrapper someItems = {
    {0, "Some constant item"},
    {1, "Another constant item"}
};

class Foo
{
public:
    void addWrapper(ItemWrapper* w) { itemwrappers.push_back(w); }
    std::vector<ItemWrapper*> itemwrappers{};
};

int main()
{
    /* Either one of these constructors would be fine */
    
    ItemWrapper someOtherItems = {
        {{0, "I'm only initializing"},
         {1, "The first two items"}},
        10}; // Infer the current length, which is 2

    ItemWrapper someOtherItems{10}; // Maximum length as argument
    someOtherItems.add({0, "I'm only initializing"});
    someOtherItems.add({1, "The first two items"});

    Foo foo;
    foo.addWrapper(someItems);
    foo.addWrapper(someOtherItems);

    for (ItemWrapper* w : foo.itemwrappers)
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < w->current_length; i++)
        {
            printf("%i %s\n", w->array[i].n, w->array[i].text);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: For truly dynamic data, where the data can be reallocated at run-time, the second requirement ([t]he pointer to the data doesn't change) might be impossible. It can be possible with an iterator-like wrapper instead of actual pointers, but if raw pointers are needed then it's not possible to do any kind of reallocation (not even the C `relloc` call can promise that). Perhaps it might be possible by using OS-native functions to always map to the same virtual address?

Comment: Ignoring excess capacity, that's [`std::span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span)

Answer (score 2):

As I understand, you want a function which takes a C-array and deduces its size, so you might do:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    void addArray(const Item* a, size_t s)
    {
        itemArraysWithTheirSize.emplace_back(a, s);
    }

    template <std::size_t N>
    void addArray(const Item (&a)[N]) { addArray(a, N); }

    std::vector<std::pair<const Item*, size_t>> itemArraysWithTheirSize{};
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/o9Eb9q8ff)

Comment: Shouldn't that be `void addArray(const Item (&a)[N]) { addArray(a, N); }` (note the capital N at the end)?

Comment: @alagner: yes. typo. but Demo was good.